# How do you manage your sqlserver database projects for new builds and migrations?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, deployment, database-deployment

How do you manage your sql server database build/deploy/migrate for visual studio projects?

We have a product that includes a reasonable database part (~100 tables, ~500 procs/functions/views), so we need to be able to deploy new databases of the current version as well as upgrade older databases up to the current version. Currently we maintain separate scripts for creation of new databases and migration between versions. Clearly not ideal, but how is anyone else dealing with this?

This is complicated for us by having many customers who each have their own db instance, rather than say just having dev/test/live instances on our own web servers, but the processes around managing dev/test/live for others must be similar.

UPDATE: I'd prefer not to use any proprietary products like RedGate's (although I have always heard they're really good and will look into that as a solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [Red-Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/index.htm) SQLCompare and SQLDataCompare to handle this.  The idea is simple.  Both compare products let you maintain a complete image of the schema or data from selected tables (e.g. configuration tables) as scripts.  You can then compare any database to the scripts and get a change script.  We keep the scripts in our Mercurial source control and tag (label) each release.  Support can then go get the script for any version and use the Redgate tools to either create from scratch or upgrade.

Redgate also has an API product that allows you to do the compare function from your code.  For example, this would allow you to have an automatic upgrade function in your installer or in the product itself.  We often use this for our hosted web apps as it allows us to more fully automate the rollout process.  In our case, we have an MSBuild task that support can execute to do an automatic rollout and upgrade.  If you distribute to third-parties, you have to pay a small additional license fee for each distribution that includes the API.

Redgate also has a tool that automatically packages a database install or upgrade.  We don't use that one as we have found that the compare against scripts for a version gives us more flexibility.

The Redgate tools also help us in development because they make it trivial to source control the schema and configuration data in a very granular way (each database object can be placed in its own file)

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked before SSDT projects appeared, but that's definitely the way I'd go nowadays, along with hand-crafting migration scripts for structural db changes where there is data that would be affected.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the MS VSTS method (2008 description [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2009/06/05/declarative-database-development.aspx)), anyone got a good article on doing this with 2010 and the pros/cons of using these tools?